# How to get free space for CD R or CD RV disks?

Tags: c#, winapi

I am writing my extension for burning various kinds of discs. There is a problem with getting free space on CD R or CD RV disks. To get free space, I use DriveInfo from System.I.O. And everything works well, except for the CD R and CD RV formats. I caught an error that tells "incorrect function". How can I read free space from such formats without DriveInfo

I tried to wrap my function in WinApi but the result is negative

long AvailableFreeSpace = driveInfo.AvailableFreeSpace;

Where driveInfo -> DriveInfo class System.I.O.

I wrapped my code in try ketch and caught this error
"Incorrect function.\r\n "[exaption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERoyv.jpg)

Comment: cd-r can only be written once, there is no "free space"

Comment: @KevinCook: in addition to "Disk At Once" writing when no further data can be added, CD-R allows for writing in multiple sessions before being finalized - so there will be "free space" if those modes are used.

Comment: I'm sure there is a better higher level API available for this, but whenever I need physical details about optical discs, I usually end up sending MMC commands directly to the device hardware via `DeviceIoControl()`